# Cypress Docker container failed to install NPM dependencies

Tags: angular, cypress

I am trying to test Angular application with Cypress Docker image. When I try to install NPM dependencies I get the error **Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in npm, previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
**

Error:

```
+ npm i

npm ERR! correctMkdir failed to make directory /.npm/_locks

npm WARN @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.6.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.18.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN acorn-import-assertions@1.7.6 requires a peer of acorn@^8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.


npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! path /.npm

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in

npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:

npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1002:1002 "/.npm"

script returned exit code 243
```

Here is the Jenkins pipeline

```
#!groovy
pipeline
{
    agent {
            // this image provides everything needed to run Cypress
            docker {
            image 'cypress/base:14'
            }
        }

    stages
    {
       stage('Run e2e tests')
        {
            
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    sh('npm i')
                    
                    //Run e2e tests
                    sh('npm run cy:run')
                }
            }
        }
        
    } //End of stages
} //End of pipeline
```

Comment: It tells you to run `sudo chown -R 1002:1002 "/.npm"` did you try it ?

Comment: Sudo is not available in Docker

Comment: Typically, things run as root by default there, so the `sudo` is not even needed.

Comment: how to use root privilege in the Docker container.  EX: docker exec -it -u root ubuntu bash